Ищу асинхронную библиотеку для взаимодействия с Telegra.ph API на Python 3.12
Трубуется асинхронная библиотека для взаимодействия с Telegra.ph API на Python 3.12.
Всё перерыл, не нашёл решения - все библиотеки устарели. Самому писать aiohttp-клиент и мучаться с HTML2Node не хочется.
Подскажите пожалуйста,  может кто-то знает такую библиотеку или другой выход?

Software Recommendations

telegraph-api 1.1.0 TelegraphAPI Asynchronus Python wrapper for telgra.ph API Released: Sep 25, 2022
